# Prolog Beginner - macbook

Tags: prolog

Current college student here and have to learn Prolog this semester. Wanted to mess around and get ahead and learn it before we actually get into any assignments and I am lost lol.

I am creating a project for a program where it is dedicated to movies

I have my movie.pl file with things such as:

```
%acted_in(person,movie).
acted_in(brad_pitt,babel).
acted_in(cate_blanchette,babel).
acted_in(sharlto_copley,district_9). 
acted_in(david_james,district_9).

%directed(person,movie).
directed(alejandro_inarritu,babel).
directed(neill_blomkamp,district_9).

%released(movie,year).
released(babel,2006).
released(district_9,2009).
```

Those are just some of the ones I have in there. Now my teacher does have stuff up already since he recommended we went ahead and tried our own programs. He went ahead and gave us a makefile that is supposed to work with everything just needed to change the EXE=movie.

The part where I am lost is on the main.pl. Say I have multiple different questions to put in, how would I add them? Do I just add a writeln with a new question under the previous print_query_false?

```
%main.pl
:- [movie].
print_query_true(Q) :-
   forall(Q, writeln(true:Q)).

print_query_false(Q) :-
   forall(\+ Q, writeln(false:Q)).

main :-
   nl
   writeln( "1. Did Leonardo DiCaprio act in Babel?" ),
   print_query_true(acted_in(leonardo_dicaprio,babel)),
   print_query_false(acted_in(leonardo_dicaprio,babel)),
   nl,
   halt.
```

The last problem I have is when i try to run swipl it goes through and turns on the program. but when i type in [movie]. it just says true and doesn't show that is says compiled or anything of the sort.

Comment: You should change the title of your question. "Prolog beginner" doesn't describe the question, and the fact that you're using a MacBook (if that's what that means in your title) appears irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> The part where I am lost is on the main.pl. Say I have multiple different questions to put in, how would I add them? Do I just add a writeln with a new question under the previous print_query_false?

Yes, for example:

```
main :-
    nl,
    format( "1. Did Leonardo DiCaprio act in Babel?" ),
    nl,
    print_query_true(acted_in(leonardo_dicaprio,babel)),
    print_query_false(acted_in(leonardo_dicaprio,babel)),
    nl,
    format( "2. Was babel released in 2006?" ),
    nl,
    print_query_true(released(babel, 2006)),
    print_query_false(released(babel, 2006)),
    nl,
    format( "3. Did anyone act in both Click and The Aviator?" ), 
    nl,
    print_query_true((acted_in(X, click), acted_in(X, the_aviator))),
    print_query_false((acted_in(X, click), acted_in(X, the_aviator))),
    nl,
    format("4. Did sharlto_copley and david_james both act in district_9?"),
    nl,
    print_query_true((acted_in(sharlto_copley, district_9), acted_in(david_james, district_9))),
    print_query_false((acted_in(sharlto_copley, district_9), acted_in(david_james, district_9))),
    nl,
    format("5. Was there any two movies released in 2006 and 2009?"),
    nl,
    print_query_true((released(X, 2006), released(Y, 2009))),
    print_query_false((released(X, 2006), released(Y, 2009))),
    nl,
    format("6. What actors acted in babel or district 9?"),
    nl,
    print_query_true((acted_in(X, babel) ; acted_in(X, district_9))),
    print_query_false((acted_in(X, babel) ; acted_in(X, district_9))),
    nl,
    format("6. What actors played in babel but not in district 9?"),
    nl,
    print_query_true((acted_in(X, babel), \+ acted_in(X, district_9))),
    print_query_false((acted_in(X, babel), \+ acted_in(X, district_9))),
    nl,
    halt.
```

I changed `writeln` to `format` to get proper formatted strings in the output. Test run:

```
?- [main].
%  movie compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
% main compiled 0.00 sec, 15 clauses
true.

?- main.

1. Did Leonardo DiCaprio act in Babel?
false:acted_in(leonardo_dicaprio,babel)

2. Was babel released in 2006?
true:released(babel,2006)

3. Did anyone act in both Click and The Aviator?
false: (acted_in(_G1551,click),acted_in(_G1551,the_aviator))

4. Did sharlto_copley and david_james both act in district_9?
true: (acted_in(sharlto_copley,district_9),acted_in(david_james,district_9))

5. Was there any two movies released in 2006 and 2009?
true: (released(babel,2006),released(district_9,2009))

6. What actors acted in babel or district 9?
true: (acted_in(brad_pitt,babel);acted_in(brad_pitt,district_9))
true: (acted_in(cate_blanchette,babel);acted_in(cate_blanchette,district_9))
true: (acted_in(sharlto_copley,babel);acted_in(sharlto_copley,district_9))
true: (acted_in(david_james,babel);acted_in(david_james,district_9))

6. What actors played in babel but not in district 9?
true: (acted_in(brad_pitt,babel),\+acted_in(brad_pitt,district_9))
true: (acted_in(cate_blanchette,babel),\+acted_in(cate_blanchette,district_9))
```

SWI-Prolog have an awesome documentation so I advise you to check up the predicates used to understand them fully:

- `forall`: [forall/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2).
- `nl`: [nl/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nl/0)
- `writeln`: [writeln/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=writeln/1)
- `halt` [halt/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=halt/0)
- `format` [format/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/1)
- Compilation: [SWI-prolog compilation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%272.10%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/compilation.html%27)))

> The last problem I have is when i try to run swipl it goes through and turns on the program. but when i type in [movie]. it just says true and doesn't show that is says compiled or anything of the sort.

Make sure you are in the right directory where you have your source-files.

SWI-Prolog v6.6.4 output:

```
?- [movie].
% movie compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
true.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help..Now say I wanted to compare 2 different things, such as a character who acted in 2 separate movies. how would I do this?

  format( "3. Did anyone act in both Click and The Aviator?" ), nl,

    print_query_true((acted_in(X,Click),(acted_in(X,the_aviator)))),

    print_query_false((acted_in(X,Click),(acted_in(X,the_aviator)))),

    nl,